# Как оставлять значение в поле input

Tags: javascript, html

ниже указанным кодом выводится значение
отмеченого чекбокса построчно, а так же пустое поле input. Когда его заполнить и после выбрать следующий чекбокс значение в ранее заполненом input обнуляется. Как сделать так чтоб значение оставалось?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="sum_value" style="display: table;">

                      <div id="aaa" style="display: table-cell;">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="aaa 10" id="aaa"><span>10</span>
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div id="aaa_All">
                        <div id="aaa_B" style="display: table-cell;">
                          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="aaa_B 1" id="aaa_B">B<span>1</span>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: table-cell;">
                          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="aaa_M 2" id="aaa_M">M<span>2</span>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: table-cell;">
                          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="aaa_S 3" id="aaa_S">S<span>3</span>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="aaa_B_p_r" style="display: table-cell;">
                          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="aaa_B_r 4"
                              id="aaa_B_r"><span>4</span>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="aaa_B_p_w" style="display: table-cell;">
                          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="aaa_B_w 5"
                              id="aaa_B_w"><span>5</span>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

    <div class="column_2">
      <div class="options_sum" id="options_sum">sum: <span></span></div>
      <div class="options_value" id="options_value">seg: <p id="options_value" class="options_value"></p>

      </div>
    </div>


  
  <script>$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.sum_value input').click(function () {
      $('#options_value').html('');
      $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
         $('#options_value').append($(this).val() + '<input type="text" style="background-color: rgb(240, 54, 54);"><br>');
      });
   });
});</script>
```

Comment: Приведите полный пример с разметкой

Comment: Пожалуйста вставьте ваш минимальный вопроизводимый код, нажав на кнопку Править под вопросом, далее в редакторе вопроса нужно нажать на CTRL+M и расстваить свой код по нужным блокам. Перед тем как вставить в сообщение, пожалуйста, убедитесь что код запускается корректно, всё отображается как вам надо и нет никаких ошибок

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Добавил.